# Windows Service write to a file - UnauthorizedAccessException

Tags: c#, windows-services, file-permissions

Writing to FileSystem from Windows Service

From a console app I am able to write to a file using
    `System.IO.File.WriteAllText(@"C:\_dev\some_path\Log.txt", "new file additions");`

however using the same code in my new Windows Service I am unable to accomplish the same via the reasons below:

```
`Service cannot be started. System.Exception: unable to save file! - 
filePath=C:\_dev\some_path\Log.txt 
type=System.UnauthorizedAccessException , 
message=Access to the path 'C:\WINDOWS\system32\filePath' is denied.
innerException=, 
stackTrace=   at System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32 errorCode, String maybeFullPath)
   at System.IO.FileStream.Init(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, Int32 rights, Boolean useRights, FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize, FileOptions options, SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES secAttrs, String msgPath, Boolean bFromProxy, Boolean useLongPath, Boolean checkHost)
   at System.IO.FileStream..ctor(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize, FileOptions options, String msgPath, Boolean bFromProxy, Boolean useLongPath, Boolean checkHost)
   at System.IO.StreamWriter.CreateFile(String path, Boolean append, Boolean checkHost)
   at System.IO.StreamWriter..ctor(String path, Boolean append, Encoding encoding, Int32 bufferSize, Boolean checkHost)
   at Sys...`
```

why is the file path `C:\WINDOWS\system32\filePath` being used?  The file path I am specifying in the `WriteAllText()` is `C:\_dev\some_path\Log.txt`?

I am sure this has something to do with Idendity but I am a newbie to working with Windows Services and am sure that I am just overlooking something simple.

Current Users with Access:
1. Authenticated Users
2. System
3. Administrators (COMPUTER\Administrators)
4. Users (COMPUTER\Users)

I also tried and added these accounts but still got same error above
5. LOCAL SERVICE
6. SERVICE
7. IUSR

How can my Windows Service write to a file and why does `WriteAllText()` try to use `C:\WINDOWS\system32`.

Comment: the user you are running the process dont have privileges to write on System32 folder. Change UAC settings and write on other location

Comment: Have you tried opening Services.msc, right clicking the service and clicking properties.  On the window that pops up, click the log on Tab and try setting the account to something you know has access to the folder path you are describing?

Answer (score 2):

Still not writing to disk but got the service to start by:

1. Clicking on the Log On tab
2. Selecting "Local System account"
   a. Checking "Allow service to interact with desktop"